# Override option text color in a select component

Tags: chakra-ui

I use a select component from the chakra-react-select package:
https://github.com/csandman/chakra-react-select#variant--options-outline--filled--flushed--unstyled--default-outline

This is my component:

```
import { Flex, FormControl, FormLabel } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import {
    Select
} from "chakra-react-select";
import * as React from "react";

const SelectChoc = ({}) => {
  const colorOptions = [
    { value: "blue", label: "Blue", color: "#0052CC" },
    { value: "purple", label: "Purple", color: "#5243AA" },
    { value: "red", label: "Red", color: "#FF5630" },
    { value: "orange", label: "Orange", color: "#FF8B00" },
    { value: "yellow", label: "Yellow", color: "#FFC400" },
    { value: "green", label: "Green", color: "#36B37E" },
  ];
  return (
    <Flex justify="center" align="center" w="full">
      <FormControl p={4}>
        <FormLabel>With variant="filled"</FormLabel>
        <Select
          colorScheme="blackAlpha"
          focusBorderColor="blue.500"
          selectedOptionColorScheme="blue"
          isMulti
          name="colors"
          options={colorOptions}
          placeholder="Select some colors..."
          variant="filled"
          defaultValue={[
            { value: "blue", label: "Blue", color: "#0052CC" },
            { value: "purple", label: "Purple", color: "#5243AA" },
          ]}
        />
      </FormControl>
    </Flex>
  );
};

export default SelectChoc;
```

However in my main page where i use the component i have this theme. And due to the **color: "white"**, it makes the option text white as well.

```
 const theme = extendTheme({
  styles: {
    global: {
      body: {
        bg: "#0e0f11",
        color: "white",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Look at these picture:

1. Before clicking the selector [image]
2. When showing options available [image]

I still want to keep the theme on my page, but somehow make the text for the dropdown options black. Have tried everything. Would love some advice... :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The [chakra-react-select Styling documentation](https://github.com/csandman/chakra-react-select#styling) has the information you're looking for. The `option` > `color` should override the theme body `color`. Include the configured styles in the`chakraStyles` prop on the select.

```js
import {
    Select
} from "chakra-react-select";

const SelectChoc = ({}) => {
  const chakraStyles: ChakraStylesConfig = {
    option: (provided) => ({
      ...provided,
      color: "black" // your color here
    }),
  };

  return (
    <...OtherComponents>
        <Select
          {/* ...other options */}
          chakraStyles={chakraStyles} {/* Add configured styles here */}
        />
    </...OtherComponents>
  );
};

export default SelectChoc;
```

Here's a [Replit sandbox](https://replit.com/@toolsareplit/chakra-react-select-so) showing the color override. Styling for other parts of the `chakra-react-select` component can be applied using the same pattern.